# Odd doubling of results in jQuery/Ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax

I can not figure out why I am getting a doubling of the results from an AJAX/jQuery request.

Here is a screenshot - [image: screenshot of doubled result]

From the inspector, I can see the table is being provided twice in the HTML but when I look at the console it shows only one request and one result. Just one instance, not two so it seems it isn't being called twice.

Here is the code for the request:

```
function a_function_name(id) {          
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: my_ajax.ajax_url,      
        data: {
            action: 'myfunction',
            fid : id
        },      
    success: function (data) {
        jQuery('#jx-loading').hide();
    
        var $newTR = jQuery("<table id='mynewtable'>")
        var $newTD = jQuery("<td>",{id:'option',html:data, colspan:7}) 
        $newTR.append($newTD)

        jQuery('#options > tbody').append($newTR.insertAfter(jQuery('[data-id="' + id + '"]'))) 
    }
});
```

The html as requested:

```
<table id="options">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>column1 </th>
      <th>column2 </th>
      <th>column3 </th>
      <th>column4 </th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

sample `data` response payload -

```
<tr>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>Two</td>
  <td><select id='name' name='change' onchange='SelectChanged(this)'>
      <option value=person&nbsp;last name>person&nbsp;lastname</option>
      <option value=person&nbsp;lastname>person&nbsp;lastname</option>
    </select></td>
  <td><button id='btn1' class='button' onclick='dosomething(7, 46)'><i class='icon fas fa-globe'></i></button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>Two</td>
  <td><select id='name' name='change' onchange='SelectChanged(this)'>
      <option value=person&nbsp;lastame>person&nbsp;lastame</option>
      <option value=person&nbsp;lastame>person&nbsp;lastame</option>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td><button id='btn1' class='button' onclick='dosomething(8, 46)'><i class='icon fas fa-globe'></i></button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>Top</td>
  <td><select id='name' name='change' onchange='Changed(this)'>
      <option value=person&nbsp;lastame>person&nbsp;lastame</option>
      <option value=person&nbsp;lastame>person&nbsp;lastame</option>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td><button id='btn1' class='button btn' onclick='dosomething(10, 46)'><i class='icon fas fa-globe'></i></button></td>
</tr>
```

EDIT -

So others can see my thinking that lead to being overcomplex :

I figured that must have been the case somewhere along the line. So that others in the future might be able to understand my thought process that lead here - and to avoid doing it, the issue I started with was having all the data stuck in one column of the table that I was appending to. I finally got the content into its own table, but the content wouldnt format into a row. So I added the row var in order to keep the content in a row, that became inside the table, inside the appended element. This obviously got way over complex

Comment: So you create a table and call it a TR and you append a td to the table? `var $newTR = jQuery("<table id='options-table'>")` <-- huh??

Comment: you can verify how many times the AJAX call is occurring by inspecting F12 dev tools -> network tab

Comment: Correct. There is the main table and there is the table below it inside of the main table. If there is a better way I am all ears and happy to learn

Comment: Funny that `#options` seems to be a `<table>` and `newTR` is also a `<table>`... So it seems like you `insertAfter` AND `append` the `<table>` `newTR`... --IMPOSSIBLE to deduct anything here with that mix of wrong logic and bad naming. **Post your HTML**

Comment: @devlincarnate just once. One call and one response

Comment: @louyspatricebessette I have posted the requested html although your down vote is not appreciated. If youre not interested in helping that is fine but the solution could help someone else and thus the downvote is unwarranted.

Comment: Downvote is a tool to force improvements on the question. As I see, it worked. Now I have an additional question about the `data` expected... Is that a whole table row? Can you post what the ajax `data` is for one request?

Comment: No not really. You simply asking "forced" me to do it. It didnt improve the question. Try simply asking - its much more friendly. The data is a minimum of one row or can be multiple rows

Comment: I am asking for more details... As your question actually is unclear and need more degugging details. That is why the downvote. I can undo the downvote after you edit with the relevant details.

Comment: added the `data` as requested

Comment: So that is a whole table...

Comment: is that a question or a statement?

Comment: A Statement....

Comment: right. I am uncertain of the context. Are you proposing changing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the Ajax request is **replacing** the table whole content (the `<tbody>` content)...

That makes it way simpler than the code you posted.

```js
// Assuming this would be received by Ajax
let data = `<tr>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>Two</td>
  <td><select id='name' name='change' onchange='SelectChanged(this)'>
      <option value=person&nbsp;last name>person&nbsp;lastname</option>
      <option value=person&nbsp;lastname>person&nbsp;lastname</option>
    </select></td>
  <td><button id='btn1' class='button' onclick='dosomething(7, 46)'><i class='icon fas fa-globe'></i></button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>Two</td>
  <td><select id='name' name='change' onchange='SelectChanged(this)'>
      <option value=person&nbsp;lastame>person&nbsp;lastame</option>
      <option value=person&nbsp;lastame>person&nbsp;lastame</option>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td><button id='btn1' class='button' onclick='dosomething(8, 46)'><i class='icon fas fa-globe'></i></button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>Top</td>
  <td><select id='name' name='change' onchange='Changed(this)'>
      <option value=person&nbsp;lastame>person&nbsp;lastame</option>
      <option value=person&nbsp;lastame>person&nbsp;lastame</option>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td><button id='btn1' class='button btn' onclick='dosomething(10, 46)'><i class='icon fas fa-globe'></i></button></td>
</tr>`

function a_function_name(id) {

  // I'm "simulating" the ajax response here.
  // So here is what should be in the "success" callback

  jQuery('#jx-loading').hide();
  $("#options tbody").html(data)

  // Yes... Just that!

}

a_function_name()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="options">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>column1 </th>
      <th>column2 </th>
      <th>column3 </th>
      <th>column4 </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

**Addon explanations:**

Now why the table was appearing twice with your code?

Notice that line:

```
jQuery('#options > tbody').append($newTR.insertAfter(jQuery('[data-id="' + id + '"]')))
```

The `newTR` is inserted after an element targeted by this selector: `[data-id="' + id + '"]` in `$newTR.insertAfter(jQuery('[data-id="' + id + '"]'))`

Then it is appended because `.insertAfter` returns the `$newTR` element after it has executed... So in a second "step" it is like you have: `jQuery('#options > tbody').append($newTR)`

Comment: Thank you for the detailed example. I am confirming that I should remove the rest of what is in the `success function` and simply replace with just the `  $("#options tbody").html(data)`, correct?

Comment: Yes.. I don't know why you tried to create some elements here. You overcomplicated the problem (But don't worry, it happens to many)

Comment: I figured that must have been the case somewhere along the line. So that others in the future might be able to understand my thought process that lead here - and to avoid doing it, the issue I started with was having all the `data` stuck in one column of the table that I was appending to. I finally got the content into its own table, but the content wouldnt format into a row. So I added the row var in order to keep the content in a row, that became inside the table, inside the appended element. This obviously got way over complex

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing out how much easier this could have been and helping remove the layers of unnecessary complexity.

Comment: I added some explanations about the table appearing twice with your code. Hoping it helps.

Comment: looks great. Thanks again